# Show $[\gamma^\mu,\eta^{\nu\lambda}I]=0$ for Dirac matrices

Tags: commutator, dirac-matrices, anticommutator

I am trying to show the following commutation relation for the Dirac matrices $\gamma^\mu$ and the metric $\eta^{\nu\lambda}$: $$2[\gamma^\mu,\eta^{\nu\lambda}I]=0$$
where $I$ is the 4x4 identity matrix and $\eta^{\nu\lambda}$ is a matrix element of the metric.

The Dirac matrices satisfy the following anti-commutation relation:
$$\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}= \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu +\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu=2\eta^{\mu\nu}I$$

Here is my attempt:
$$2[\gamma^\mu,\eta^{\nu\lambda}I]=2[\gamma^\mu,\frac{1}{2}\gamma^\nu \gamma^\lambda +\frac{1}{2}\gamma^\lambda\gamma^\nu]=[\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu \gamma^\lambda]+[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\lambda\gamma^\nu]$$$$=\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu \}\gamma^\lambda-\gamma^\nu\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\lambda\}+\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\lambda \}\gamma^\nu-\gamma^\lambda\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}$$$$=\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\lambda-\gamma^\nu\gamma^\lambda\gamma^\mu+\gamma^\mu\gamma^\lambda\gamma^\nu-\gamma^\lambda\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu$$
where I cancelled like terms in the last step.

How do I proceed further to show that $2[\gamma^\mu,\eta^{\nu\lambda}I]=0$?

Comment: You seem to be confusing Lorentz indices with spinor indices. The metric isn’t a matrix at all in spinor space.

Comment: @G.Smith Do you mean the indices on $\eta$? I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: The identity matrix commutes with all matrices. Just set $\mu$, $\nu$, and $\lambda$ to 0, for example, and write out this commutator explicitly.

Comment: @G.Smith Oh right! I am indeed wrongly thinking of $\eta^{\nu\lambda}$ as the matrix....